# Application crashed after Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000020 (code=1) - Android

Tags: android, opencv, video-capture

I am working in one android application. In my application I am capturing images with the use of opencv native camera. When I open camera to capture image, the application crashed. The log file showing "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000020 (code=1)". I don't know why it is crashed. Can anyone tell me what may the problem? This code is working in emulator. But When I am using in device it crashed. Iam using opencv face detection sample. Code snippet is given below,

```
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to load OpenCV library");
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2, this, mOpenCVCallBack))
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
        }
    }


private BaseLoaderCallback  mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                    // Load native libs after OpenCV initialization
                    System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");

                    // Create and set View
                    mView = new FdView(mAppContext);
                    mView.setDetectorType(mDetectorType);
                    mView.setMinFaceSize(0.2f);
                    setContentView(mView);
                    // Check native OpenCV camera
                    if( !mView.openCamera() ) {
                        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(mAppContext).create();
                        ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button
                        ad.setMessage("Fatal error: can't open camera!");
                        ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                            }
                        });
                        ad.show();
                    }
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };
   public FdView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        try {
            InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
            File cascadeDir = context.getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();

            mJavaDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if (mJavaDetector.empty()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
                mJavaDetector = null;
            } else
                Log.i(TAG, "Loaded cascade classifier from " + mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());

            mNativeDetector = new DetectionBasedTracker(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath(), 0);

            cascadeDir.delete();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade. Exception thrown: " + e);
        }
    }
    @Override
protected Bitmap processFrame(VideoCapture capture) {
    capture.retrieve(mRgba, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
    capture.retrieve(mGray, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_GREY_FRAME);

    if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0)
    {
        int height = mGray.rows();
        if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0);
        {
            mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
        }
        mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(mAbsoluteFaceSize);
    }

    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

    if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR)
    {
        if (mJavaDetector != null)
            mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2 // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                    , new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
    }
    else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR)
    {
        if (mNativeDetector != null)
            mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
    }

    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
        Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    try {
        Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception: " + e.getMessage());
        bmp.recycle();
        bmp = null;
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

The Log is given below.

```
I/dalvikvm-heap(  688): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.827MB for 1228816-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  688): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 7852K/8839K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  688): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1200K, 25% free 6652K/8839K, paused 24ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  688): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.827MB for 1228816-byte allocation
F/libc    (  688): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000020 (code=1)
I/DEBUG   (   83): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   83): Build fingerprint: 'softwinners/crane_q7/crane-q7:4.0.3/IML74K/20120709:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   83): pid: 688, tid: 690  >>> com.user.mailconf <<<
I/DEBUG   (   83): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000020
I/DEBUG   (   83):  r0 00000000  r1 000106e0  r2 000106e0  r3 40a091e8
I/DEBUG   (   83):  r4 50a090f8  r5 408d3c58  r6 00000000  r7 000106e0
I/DEBUG   (   83):  r8 50a09000  r9 000106e0  10 50a09100  fp 4085f394
I/DEBUG   (   83):  ip 0000001f  sp 100ffdd0  lr 4084efc4  pc 4085efac  cpsr 80000010
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 991f1f1f991f1f1f
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d18 0707070703030303  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d20 0100010001000100  d21 0100010001000100
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d26 0067006700670067  d27 0067006700670067
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d28 0067006700670067  d29 0067006700670067
I/DEBUG   (   83):  d30 00308000002b4000  d31 003b40000035c000
I/DEBUG   (   83):  scr 80000012
I/DEBUG   (   83): 
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #00  pc 00042fac  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #01  pc 00032fc0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z21dvmHeapBitmapScanWalkP10HeapBitmapPFvP6ObjectPvS3_ES3_)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #02  pc 000433c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z24dvmHeapScanMarkedObjectsv)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #03  pc 00033694  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z25dvmCollectGarbageInternalPK6GcSpec)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #04  pc 0007ba40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #05  pc 0005f656  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #06  pc 00012be4  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #07  pc 00012738  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create)
I/DEBUG   (   83): 
I/DEBUG   (   83): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4085ef8c e1a04000 e59f01e0 e1a07001 e79f5000  .@.......p...P..
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4085ef9c e5940000 e59530b0 e1500003 0a00003a  .....0....P.:...
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4085efac e590c020 e31c0101 0a000011 ebfffeb9   ...............
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4085efbc e5940000 e5903020 e3130202 08bd81f0  .... 0..........
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4085efcc e594e008 e2846010 e35e0000 08bd81f0  .....`....^.....
I/DEBUG   (   83): 
I/DEBUG   (   83): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4084efa4 e0888404 e16fcf16 e58d3004 e1a0100a  ......o..0......
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4084efb4 e1a02009 e1c66c33 e088018c e12fff3b  . ..3l......;./.
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4084efc4 e3560000 e59d3004 1afffff5 e5971010  ..V..0..........
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4084efd4 e597800c e068e001 e1a0142e e2844001  ......h......@..
I/DEBUG   (   83): 4084efe4 e2855c01 e1510004 2affffe7 e28dd00c  .\....Q....*....
I/DEBUG   (   83): 
I/DEBUG   (   83): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffd90  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffd94  408cef90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffd98  000106e0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffd9c  40fdc538  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffda0  000106e0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffda4  41165c10  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffda8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdac  80000000  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdb0  40a0a0b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdb4  4085ef28  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdb8  41165bf0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdbc  408d3c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdc0  4116c158  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdc4  408d3c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdc8  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdcc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   83): #00 100ffdd0  00100000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdd4  10000100  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdd8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffddc  0001079c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffde0  50a09000  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffde4  4084efc4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83): #01 100ffde8  408d3c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdec  80000000  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdf0  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdf4  000106c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdf8  000106e0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffdfc  408cef90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe00  fffffe4c  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe04  7fffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe08  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe0c  0008b5db  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe10  408d3c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):     100ffe14  4085f3c8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  992): debuggerd: Jul  9 2012 16:58:08
I/ActivityManager(  144): Process com.user.mailconf (pid 688) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  144): Force removing ActivityRecord{412fd3f8 com.user.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity}: app died, no saved state
D/V4L2CameraDevice(   87): stopDevice
D/CallbackNotifier(   87): storeMetaDataInBuffers, false
I/WindowManager(  144): WIN DEATH: Window{41274608 com.user.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity paused=false}
W/WindowManager(  144): Force-removing child win Window{4133c958 SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{41274608 com.user.mailconf/org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity paused=false}
D/Zygote  (   85): Process 688 terminated by signal (11)
I/WindowManager(  144): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
W/WindowManager(  144): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager(  144): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@4119ca18 does not exist
W/WindowManager(  144):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7156)
W/WindowManager(  144):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7147)
W/WindowManager(  144):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1529)
W/WindowManager(  144):     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:417)
W/WindowManager(  144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
I/WindowManager(  144): WIN DEATH: null
V/TabletStatusBar(  210): setLightsOn(true)
D/V4L2CameraDevice(   87): cedarx_hardware_exit ok
W/CameraService(   87): native_window_api_disconnect failed: Broken pipe (-32), api: 6
I/CameraService(   87): Destroying camera 0
D/CallbackNotifier(   87): storeMetaDataInBuffers, false
W/AudioFlinger(   87): session id 7 not found for pid 87
W/AudioFlinger(   87): session id 8 not found for pid 87
D/dalvikvm(  337): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 162K, 35% free 7073K/10823K, paused 26ms
W/InputManagerService(  144): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 688 uid 10038
D/dalvikvm(  337): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 267K, 35% free 7128K/10823K, paused 24ms
I/WindowManager(  144): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
I/wpa_supplicant(  455): [CTRL_IFACE]SIGNAL_POLL
D/dalvikvm(  337): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 31% free 7536K/10823K, paused 3ms+5ms
D/dalvikvm(  337): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 654K, 33% free 7322K/10823K, paused 26ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  337): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.533MB for 1286224-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  337): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 21% free 8575K/10823K, paused 24ms
D/dalvikvm(  337): GC_CONCURRENT freed 60K, 18% free 8964K/10823K, paused 2ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm(  337): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2240K, 28% free 7843K/10823K, paused 2ms+3ms
I/WindowManager(  144): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
I/WindowManager(  144): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
I/wpa_supplicant(  455): [CTRL_IFACE]SIGNAL_POLL
I/ActivityManager(  144): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.user.mailconf/.activity.Accounts} from pid 337
D/ViewRootImpl(  144): pckname = com.user.mailconf
D/dalvikvm(  993): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  144): Start proc com.user.mailconf for activity com.user.mailconf/.activity.Accounts: pid=993 uid=10038 gids={3003, 1015, 1006}
I/dalvikvm(  993): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
D/OpenGLRenderer(  337): Flushing caches (mode 1)
D/dalvikvm(   85): GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 7% free 5611K/6019K, paused 3ms+37ms
D/OpenGLRenderer(  337): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/dalvikvm(   85): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 7% free 5611K/6019K, paused 3ms+10ms
D/dalvikvm(   85): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 7% free 5611K/6019K, paused 7ms+4ms
I/ActivityThread(  993): Pub com.user.mailconf.messageprovider: com.user.mailconf.provider.MessageProvider
I/HubMail (  993): Loading preferences from DB into Storage
D/dalvikvm(  993): GC_CONCURRENT freed 169K, 6% free 5929K/6279K, paused 2ms+9ms
I/HubMail (  993): Preferences load took 45ms
I/wpa_supplicant(  455): [CTRL_IFACE]SIGNAL_POLL
```

Comment: You should give a code snippet of how you called opencv. In lieu of that information, I'm leaning towards thinking that this is a bug in the android opencv bindings.

Comment: try to debug first and track the Heap size  that may be due to Image Capture is Too large to compressed 
try to calculate the Image Size 
from its dimenssion Using This 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: @yiding: Thanks. I am using "opencv face detection" sample code. I have updated my question with vode snippet. But this working in emulator. But not working in android tablet device?

Comment: @Usman Kurd: Thanks for the response. I will check it what you mentioned.

Comment: Can you please add the JNI functions that you've used? "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)" - this type of error occurs when a memory is not allocated or freed properly. Check again your codes at native side.